# Cannot deserialize subclass in Find statement in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, geojson

I have this class

```
public class TestClass
{
     public DateTime date;
     public ObjectId _id;
     public GeoJsonGeometry<GeoJson2DCoordinates> loc;
}
```

When I insert data into MongoDB, it works perfectly!
When I read data, I get an exception saying that the subclass TestClass.loc cannot be deserialized.

If I execute the find statement without retrieving the loc property, the code works.

How exactly can I deserialize the subclass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by writing my own serializer. Since I wanted to work with an abstract class this is what I wrote.

```
public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
{
    return new GeoJsonObjectSerializer<T>().Deserialize(bsonReader, nominalType, options):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GeoJsonGeometry` is an abstract class. You can't instantiate an abstract class (and the deserializer doesn't have knowledge of what original type was serialized, as it wasn't stored in the BSON document).

The simplest solution is to use a more specific type, maybe `GeoJsonPoint` for example.

Or, you could investigate writing a custom serializer as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#customizing-serialization).